# Compare three dataframe and create a new column in one of the dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am comparing two data frames with master_df and create a new column based on a new condition if available.

for example I have master_df and two region df as asia_df and europe_df. I want to check if company of master_df is available in any of the region data frames and create a new column as region as Europe and Asia

```
master_df
company product
ABC    Apple
BCA    Mango
DCA    Apple
ERT    Mango
NFT    Oranges

europe_df
account sales 
ABC      12 
BCA      13
DCA      12

asia_df
account sales 
DCA      15
ERT      34
```

My final output dataframe is expected to be

```
company product region
ABC    Apple    Europe
BCA    Mango    Europe
DCA    Apple    Europe
DCA    Apple    Asia
ERT    Mango    Asia
NFT    Oranges  Others
```

When I try to merge and compare, some datas are removed. I need help on how to fix this issues

```
final_df = europe_df.merge(master_df, left_on='company', right_on='account', how='left').drop_duplicates()

final1_df = asia_df.merge(master_df, left_on='company', right_on='account', how='left').drop_duplicates()


final['region'] = np.where(final_df['account'] == final_df['company'] ,'Europe','Others')
final['region'] = np.where(final1_df['account'] == final1_df['company'] ,'Asia','Others')
```

Answer (score 1):

First using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) concat the dataframes `asia_df` and `europe_df` then use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge them with `master_df`, finally use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill `NaN` values in `Region` with `Others`:

```
r = pd.concat([europe_df.assign(Region='Europe'), asia_df.assign(Region='Asia')])\
      .rename(columns={'account': 'company'})[['company', 'Region']]

df = master_df.merge(r, on='company', how='left')
df['Region'] = df['Region'].fillna('Others')
```

Result:

```
print(df)
  company  product  Region
0     ABC    Apple  Europe
1     BCA    Mango  Europe
2     DCA    Apple  Europe
3     DCA    Apple    Asia
4     ERT    Mango    Asia
5     NFT  Oranges  Others
```

Comment: @JackJack Does this answered your question?